# how to update cocos2d version in a game

Tags: iphone, ios4, cocos2d-iphone, ios-simulator

I've been using an older version of cocos2d for iPhone for an existing project -- never change a running system. Now I'd like to upgrade to a more recent version of cocos2d... I replaced all the cocos2d classes with old one; I get this error:

```
duplicate symbol _main in /Users/aqtoor1/Desktop/BlocksParty
[music] co/build/Debug-iphoneos/libcocos2d libraries.a
(main-D28BA02B69A7176A.o) and /Users/aqtoor1/Desktop/BlocksParty
[music] co/build/BlocksParty.build/Debug-iphoneos/BlocksParty.build/Objects-normal
/armv6/main.o
```

I replaced old cocos2d file for second with-in couple of days last time; I am getting some framework missing error now getting this one. I'm just stuck. :( 
Need help, I have to get this working to my boss, today.
:(

Comment: what was the older version number and new version number?

Comment: dnt knw abt old one but new is 0.99.5 im using this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it by just replacing the cocos2d files - dragging them into the project. But before doing this make a copy of your project with the previous version (if still possible) That did it for me. As far as I know cocos2d is just a set of imported files anyway. The templates etc did not change, so there was no need to uninstall or reinstall anything.

Comment: @user387184 no dear .. mess with lots oferrors ... cclable etc missing .. even i copy these file manually from old directory

Comment: @lukman .. thank i have change all the remaned classes ... now getting a singel error
library not found for -lcocos2d libraries